# Callbacks not working for TikTok Login kit on Android

Tags: android, tiktok

I have been following the [documentation](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-android) for integrating TikTok's login kit for Android. Here is my complete Activity for receiving the callbacks from the IAPIEventHandler interfact provided by the TikTok SDK:

```
internal class ATikTokAuth : BaseActivity(), IApiEventHandler {

private val clientKey = TIKTOK_CLIENT_KEY

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.a_tik_tok_auth)

    val tiktokOpenConfig = TikTokOpenConfig(clientKey)
    TikTokOpenApiFactory.init(tiktokOpenConfig)

    val tikTokOpenApi = TikTokOpenApiFactory.create(this)
    tikTokOpenApi.handleIntent(intent, this)

    val request = Authorization.Request()
    request.scope = "user.info.basic"
    request.state = "starting"
    request.callerLocalEntry = "com.package.name.ATikTokAuth"

    tikTokOpenApi.authorize(request)


}

override fun onReq(request: BaseReq?) {

    Timber.d("onRequest called: ${request?.extras}")

}

override fun onResp(resp: BaseResp?) {

    Timber.d("onResponse: isSuccess: ${resp?.isSuccess} If not, error: ${resp?.errorMsg}")
    if (resp is Authorization.Response) {

        val code = resp.authCode

        Timber.d("onResponse authcode: $code ")

        requestAccessToken(resp.authCode)



    }


}


override fun onErrorIntent(intent: Intent?) {

    Timber.d("onErrorIntent ${intent?.extras}")

}
}
```

Running this code creates the webview for the user to select a means to log in to TikTok and connect that their TikTok account to my app, but after authorization the user is returned to this activity without onResp being called. onErrorIntent() is called when the webview is launched, but the intent has no data and thus no information useful for debugging.

Also, Although the documentation initializes TikTokOpenConfig like this:

```
TikTokOpenConfig tiktokOpenConfig = new TikTokOpenConfig(clientKey);
TikTokOpenApiFactory.init(new TikTokOpenConfig(tiktokOpenConfig));
```

The TikTokOpenConfig only takes a string argument of clientKey, so I assumed it should be

```
  val tiktokOpenConfig = TikTokOpenConfig(clientKey)
    TikTokOpenApiFactory.init(tiktokOpenConfig)
```

I saw no other way since the code in the documentation wouldn't even compile

TikTok is declared as

```
implementation 'com.bytedance.ies.ugc.aweme:opensdk-oversea-external:0.2.0.2'
```

in my manifest. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should add android:exported="true" in manifest file.

```
<activity
  android:name=".ATikTokAuth"
  android:exported="true">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the initialization of tikTokOpenConfig

```
val tiktokOpenConfig = TikTokOpenConfig(clientKey)
TikTokOpenApiFactory.init(tiktokOpenConfig)
```

into a custom App class.

Answer (score 0):

First if you are trying to tikTok login kit in India,First you have to use VPN. and second if you want callback - you should add  `tikTokOpenApi.handleIntent(intent, this)` into onNewIntent() method,i solved my issue using this.

Steps:

1. use VPN
2. add `tikTokOpenApi.handleIntent(intent, this)` in override `onNewIntent()`  method

Login Success!